# Flutter tflite plugin not doing recognitions in release version of app

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying to use the flutter [tflite plugin](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite) in my app and so far have been testing it in dev/debug where it is working i.e. when I run the following

```
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
        path: croppedFile.path,   // required
        imageMean: 0.0,   // defaults to 117.0
        imageStd: 255.0,  // defaults to 1.0
        numResults: 2,    // defaults to 5
        threshold: 0.2,   // defaults to 0.1
        asynch: true      // defaults to true
    );
```

it does give me back some recognitions. However when I make a release version of the same code it does not return any recognitions when run on the same device with same input data. I am making the release version using following steps:

```
//step 1
flutter build appbundle

// step 2
java -jar bundletool-all-1.3.0.jar build-apks --bundle=app-release.aab --output=app-release.apks --ks=key.jks --ks-pass= --ks-key-alias=key --key-pass=

// step 3
java -jar bundletool-all-1.3.0.jar install-apks --apks=app-release.apks
```

I have also added following in my android build.gradle

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'tflite'
    noCompress 'lite'
}
```

How is it possible to get a different result in release whereas the same code works in debug version of app? What am I missing in my setup?

NOTE: I can only test this on Android

**UPDATE**

Digging further, I ran the app in profile mode and found following logs (Note: These only show up in profile mode so I am not sure how far it is from the release version. Also, I don't get these error when running in debug):

```
2020-11-08 20:04:34.623 4869-4940/com.flutterApp.gng I/flutter: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.getInputTensor(int)' on a null object reference, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.getInputTensor(int)' on a null object reference
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.feedInputTensor(TflitePlugin.java:326)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.feedInputTensorImage(TflitePlugin.java:371)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:477)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:102)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.Messag
...
2020-11-08 02:08:07.438 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.453 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.460 23087-23136/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 89 with tag 6b55000000000(439632) for uid -1 failed errno=-24
2020-11-08 02:08:07.460 23087-23136/? I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocketFd(89, 439632, -1) failed with errno-24
2020-11-08 02:08:07.469 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.486 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.521 657-657/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 2 lines
2020-11-08 02:08:07.540 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.542 22602-22654/com.flutterApp.gng I/flutter: Found 3 faces
2020-11-08 02:08:07.557 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.566 1449-2272/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 2861259366, maxLowBytes : 524288000
2020-11-08 02:08:07.577 22602-22654/com.flutterApp.gng I/flutter: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:427)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:465)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:102)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.588 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.608 22602-22654/com.flutterApp.gng I/flutter: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:427)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:465)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:102)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.622 657-657/? I/HWComposer: getActiveConfigs: Attempted to access invalid display -1
2020-11-08 02:08:07.641 22602-22654/com.flutterApp.gng I/flutter: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:427)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.<init>(TflitePlugin.java:465)
        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:102)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1
```

As I don't see the behavior in debug mode, I am still confused on what is going on in the app when running the release version.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found an answer?

Comment: so far no luck.

Comment: Did you end up using a different package?

Comment: yes, tflite_flutter & the associated tflite_flutter_helper seemed to work for my model but I only tested with a couple of devices so far.